# How to set the destination of intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm looking for something that allows me to change the destination of the intent. Here's why:
I (in class `MyActivity`) recieve an intent from one of the activities (`Starter`) and I want to send the same intent to other activity (`Result`):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
//do some stuff here
startActivity(intent);
```

I know that now it will take me back to `MyAcitivity`, so: how do I change the destination from the `MyActivity` to `Result`? I came across `intent.setAction()` function, but I cannot find any implementation other than calling features of the phone, like making a call.

Comment: Why not simply create a new intent?

Comment: I know that it's the simplest answer, but - as for me - it looks super unefficient, beacuse requires twice as much memory. I'm looking for something smooth.

Comment: I believe that, you trying  to pass received data to next intent,if yes please update us.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do and I believe that all I need to do is just to change the destination of the intent. Now I'm checking the answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intent.setClassName()` method will help you to set different destination

Comment: Okay, it looks like an answer I was looking for, but yet I have to implement it properly, so I won't mark this as a solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can send your extras to another activity from ClassA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClassA.this, ClassB.class);
                intent.putExtra("A", "A");
                startActivity(intent);
```

And receive it at ClassB:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.containsKey("A")) {
            //do your stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do standard intent and sending data from 'Starter' to 'Result' (because I think that it's how your code works) is not an option for me and my application, because I will have to send this same intent from 'Result' to another activity and so on. I just need a method to change the destination.

Comment: Maybe you should try with `SharedPreferences`. You can access  `SharedPreferences` from any activity. Destination is not important.

Comment: But I need to send a two-dimensional float array and two bundles, so it won't "fit" in shared preferences, beacuse of not being "primitive".